# tensorflow 1.1 version download on Windows

Tags: tensorflow, download, downgrade

I'd like to download 1.1.0 version tensorflow.
But they don't support that version with pip anymore.
How can I download it?
or is there any helpful things that can help to fix codes from low version to latest version?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
pip install tensorflow==<version>
```

If it doesn't work, please try the below

In https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.1.0/ download .whl of the version you need and install it using `pip`.

Comment: They don't support 1.1 version with pypi anymore I think. It's possible to download from 1.2 version.

Comment: Hi Amily, please check whether you could download from this link https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.1.0/#files